# Redirect outcomming traffic to local server

Tags: iptables, webserver

I have a Apache web server set which listens on port 4000 and I want to use this (local) server as a kind of proxy.

The idea is to redirect all the local outcomming HTTP traffic (port `80`) to my server at `127.0.0.1:4000`. Of course, the server must be able to send request on port `80`.

I tried to update `iptables` like this :

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4000
```

Obviously it does not work because the traffic from my server is also redirected to itself.

The question is: how can I only authorize HTTP request from my server?

**Example:**

1. A request is sent to www.google.com
2. The request is redirected to my server (`127.0.0.1:4000`)
3. The server receives the request, do some stuff, then sends a request to www.google.com

I managed to do the first part (2.) but because of that my server cannot access www.google.com as it is also redirected to itself.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you saying you only want local clients to connect to the webserver? Why not just configure apache to listen on that port and do Host-based access control in `httpd.conf` ?

Comment: @Bratchley What I want is to redirect all HTTP requests to my server and then let my server forward the request to an outsude website (i.e. Google.com). I am aware that it is pointless as it is done locally but it is just for demo purpose.

Comment: @Bratchley As my post was not very clear I added an example.

Comment: Haven't done this before but have you tried adding an `iptables` rule earlier than your `DNAT` rule so that it exits without reaching the DNAT if the source port is the one associated with the proxy?

Comment: If you can't match on the source port (dynamically allocated) you might try matching based on `--uid-owner` supposing that's unique to the application doing the proxy.

Comment: @Bratchley What do you mean by before the DNAT rule? For the `--uid-owner` trick I can't test it right now but I will try as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: iptables rules are usually applied in order. I was thinking of doing a `-j RETURN` before the `DNAT` rule so the execution is never allowed to go that far down the ruleset and so the traffic doesn't get redirected.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to use netfilter for that. You need a reverse proxy[1], like that nginx or apache can do.

If you wish to use iptable, you could filter from the incomming interface like :

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4000
```

[1] http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: I totally agree that it will better with a reverse proxy but as it is just for basic demo I want to make it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Accordind to @Bratchley comments, I managed to make it work by adding the `--uid-owner` option.

This is the command that I use:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4000
```

As the apache server has a specific user, only the traffic from the uid 1000 is redirected.